# How can I select an entire row without selecting rows where a certain column value is duplicated?

Tags: sql, mysql

How can I select an entire row without selecting rows where a certain column value is duplicated?

#### EDIT:

Sorry my question is a bit vague.  Assuming i have a table with two columns: `names` and `score`.  There are duplicate values in `names`.  I want to select *distinct* names and also select their `score`s.

Comment: could you give us some examples to clear this up?

Comment: 'entire row' is singular, no risk of duplicates

Comment: How would you choose which row to keep?

Comment: Re Edit: If you select a (random) distinct Name, you select a random Score.

Comment: your edit is just as vague.  say you have 4 rows: `joe - 5`, `sam - 3`, `bill - 9`, and `joe - 2`.  You only want the 3 distinct names back, one row for each: sam, joe and bill.  However, what do you do with the 5 and 2 score rows for joe? combine them by sum, take the min or max? or what??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the edited information given, this will use the [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function to produce the distinct names and a comma-delimited list of scores. If more appropriate, you could substitute another aggregate function (e.g., [MIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min), [MAX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max), [SUM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum)) for the GROUP_CONCAT.

```
SELECT Name, GROUP_CONCAT(Score)
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY Name
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the DISTINCT clause on the columns you don't want duplicates of.

Answer (score 1):

Using the following example data...

```
name   score
-----  -----
James     10
James     12
Lisa      45
John      42
```

...the following queries should return the third and fourth row.

```
select name, score
  from table
 where name in(select name 
                 from table
                group by name having count(*) = 1);
```

...less clear, but probable more efficient on MySQL.

```
select t1.name, t1.score
  from (select name 
          from table
         group by name having count(*) = 1
       ) t1
  join table t2 on(t1.name = t2.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

based on your latest edit, try this:

```
select 
    name, SUM(score) AS TotalScore
    from YourTable
    group by name
```